# Which are the WebSql limit in IOS for WebApps?

Tags: web-applications, mobile, safari, offline, web-sql

I'm working in a **Offline WebApp** (NOT NATIVE) for iPad Mini (ios 6.0) and i need to store a lot of information, LocalStorage it's limited from 2.5 to 5 Mb and **i need at least 300 Mb...** Any recomendation?

Comment: Did you look into SQLite?

Comment: SQLite it's for native applications... This is only a webapp. http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008134

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL has "no limit" on homescreen apps in iOS7, I've tested upto 450MB before my homescreen app continually crashes. Doesn't even ask for permission too which is nice